# How to include zero flux boundary conditions?

Tags: python, finite-difference, boundary-conditions, differential-equations

I am trying to solve the following differential equation in the domain of $\theta \in [0, 2 \pi]$ using finite differences scheme:

For $0< \theta \leq \pi$
\begin{align}
\rho_i^{n+1}=\rho_i^{n}+D\frac{\Delta t}{\Delta\theta^2}[\rho^n_{i+1}-2\rho^n_i+\rho^n_{i-1}]-\beta \frac{\Delta t}{\Delta\theta}[\rho^n_i-\rho^n_{i-1}]I_{1}(\theta, t)
+\beta\Delta t\rho_{i}^n[2\rho_{i}^n(\theta+\pi)-2\rho_{i}^n(\theta)] 
\end{align}

\begin{align}
I_{1}(\theta, t) = \int_{\theta}^{\theta+\pi} \rho(\theta', t)d\theta' - \int_{0}^{\theta} \rho(\theta', t) - \int_{\theta+\pi}^{2\pi} \rho(\theta', t) d \theta'
\end{align}

For $\pi<\theta < 2\pi$:
\begin{align}
\rho_i^{n+1}=\rho_i^{n}+D\frac{\Delta t}{\Delta \theta^2}[\rho^n_{i+1}-2\rho^n_i+\rho^n_{i-1}]-\beta\frac{\Delta t}{\Delta t\theta}[\rho^n_i-\rho^n_{i-1}]I_{2}(\theta, t)
+\beta\Delta t\rho_{i}^n[2\rho_{i}^n(\theta-\pi)-2\rho_{i}^n(\theta)]
\end{align}

\begin{align}
I_{2}(\theta, t) = \int_{0}^{\theta-\pi}\rho(\theta', t)d\theta' + \int_{0}^{2\pi} \rho(\theta', t) d\theta' - \int_{\theta - \pi}^{\theta} \rho(\theta') d\theta'
\end{align}

I have added zero flux boundary conditions using:
\begin{align}
    \frac{\partial{\rho}}{\partial\theta} &\approx \frac{\rho_{i}^{n} - \rho_{i-1}^{n}}{\Delta \theta} = 0
\end{align}

Then, $\rho_{i}^{n} = \rho_{i-1}^{n}$ should assure zero flux boundary conditions.

Here is my code:

```
#1. Import libraries
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy as sci

from scipy import integrate
from matplotlib import cm
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D


#2. Setup 
ntheta = 41
dtheta = 2 / (ntheta - 1)
nt = 500     # the number of timesteps 
D = 1.     # Diffusion parameter
beta = 5. #0.  # Advection parameter CHANGE 0 to 5 and viceversa
sigma = .2 # For Counrat number
dt = sigma * dtheta**2 / D # dt is defined using sigma


rho = np.zeros(ntheta)                   # Array with ntheta elements all equal to 1.

rhon = np.zeros(ntheta) # rhon, to advance the solution in time
theta = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, ntheta)

for i in range(len(theta)):
  if theta[i] <= (np.pi - 0.25):
    low = i

for j in range(len(theta)):
  if theta[j] <= (np.pi + 0.25):
    up = j

rho[low:up] = 2 #the area under the curve should be 1.
angle = []

for i in range(len(theta)):
    if theta[i]==np.pi:
        angle=i
    

#3. Solve the EDO (iterate finite difference scheme)
for n in range(nt):  #iterate through time
    rhon = rho.copy() ## copy of the existing values of rho into rhon
    for i in range(1,ntheta-1): # iterate through angle (space)
        if theta[i] <= np.pi: 
          #Using second-order central, first-order backward difference techniques, generalization of the Second Fundamental Theorem of Calculus.
            rho[i] = rhon[i] + D * dt / dtheta**2 * (rhon[i+1] - 2 * rhon[i] + rhon[i-1]) - beta * dt / dtheta * (rhon[i] - rhon[i-1]) * ((sci.integrate.simpson(rhon[i:i+angle], theta[i:i+angle])) - sci.integrate.simpson(rhon[:i], theta[:i]) - sci.integrate.simpson(rhon[i+angle:], theta[i+angle:])) - 2 * beta * dt * rhon[i] * (rhon[i+angle] - rhon[i])
        else:
            rho[i] = rhon[i] + D * dt / dtheta**2 * (rhon[i+1] - 2 * rhon[i] + rhon[i-1]) - beta * dt / dtheta * (rhon[i] - rhon[i-1]) * ((sci.integrate.simpson(rhon[:i-angle], theta[:i-angle])) + sci.integrate.simpson(rhon[i:], theta[i:]) - sci.integrate.simpson(rhon[i-angle:i], theta[i-angle:i])) - 2 * beta * dt * rhon[i] * (rhon[i] - rhon[i-angle])
        
    rho[0] = rho[1]
    rho[len(rhon)-1] = rho[len(rhon)-2]

plt.plot(theta, rho)
plt.ylim (0, 2)
plt.axhline(y=0.16, linestyle='--', color='k') # Area = b*h i.e 1 = 2*pi*h => h = 1/2pi
plt.xlabel("Theta")
plt.ylabel("Rho")
plt.show()
```

The initial area under the curve is equal to 1, then, in zero flux this should be constant $Area = 1 = b h = 2 \pi h$, $h \approx 0.16$. However, this seems to works only when $\beta=0$ (i.e the area is always 1.), otherwise, the area under the curve is less than 1 (e.g. when $\beta = 5.$)

Please, could you help me to find my mistakes or misunderstandings?